# How do i start a process with arguments using the Win32 API?

Tags: c, winapi, process

I have been googling a bit, but did not find what i was looking for.

I want to start a process with arguments(in C) using the win32 API.

Does anybody have some examples or pointers which i can use/see?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The win32 [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the RTL [`_spawnl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function to create child processes with arguments (handy if you don't need the extra stuff provided by `CreateProcess`, though this is not strictly WinAPI)